# How to show html result form a texterea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

In a page of my web, I have a textarea to write html code. How to show this html result of this textarea into a other view under this texterea.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 2):

### You are looking for a WYSIWYG for angular:

1. [Angular WYSIWYG directive](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg)
2. [textangular](http://textangular.com/)
3. [angular-redactor](https://github.com/TylerGarlick/angular-redactor)
4. [angular-froala](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala)

***List provided here as well: http://ngmodules.org/tags/wysiwyg***

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="description" content="quick edit panel" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
        <div class="prompt" contentEditable=true 
             style="padding:5px;
                    background-color:black;
                    height:28px;
                    color:white;
                    font-family:'courier new'">
            write a html code  <span style="background-color:blue;">here</span>
        </div>
        <div class="result"> 
            write a html code  <span style="background-color:blue;">here</span>
        </div> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $('.prompt').focus();

            $('.prompt').keypress(function(event){
                if ( event.which == 13 ) {
                    var resultado = $('.prompt').html();
                    console.log(resultado);
                    $('.result').append($('<div/>').html(resultado).text()+"<br>");
                    $('.prompt').html('');
                    $('.prompt').focus();
                }
            });

        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add code explanation it helps for people to understand